# Can We Have multiple service discovery Instance

Tags: microservices, api-gateway, service-discovery

I want to know that can we have multiple service discovery instance.If Yes than have service call have been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Which service discovery tool or aproach are you refering to?

- DNS - can be distrbuted by nature is is "eventually consistent" according to the CAP theorem
- Consul as a popular service discovery solution also supports cluster setup and they take care of master elections etc..

Maybe you can be more specific with your question?

Comment: Hi Daniel,Thanks for Your reply,                                                                                                                  Actually I am not hands on micro-services.I want to know that I created 2 eureka instances and there are 10 services which need to register with above mention eureka services.So how they will choose that which service register with which eureka service.

Comment: I can't speak for Eureka, but Consul supports registering multiple instances of an application for a given service. When other applications query the service catalog, they will receive a list of available instance endpoints to which they can connect. This model assumes that all instances of a registered application have access to the same dataset, or are stateless.See https://learn.hashicorp.com/consul/getting-started/services for details on registering and querying services.